# How do I use an external EQU in an expression in MASM 5.10

Tags: assembly, masm, x86-16

I'm trying to split a very large .ASM file into several external libraries leaving only my main program in main.asm.

This is a game, so I was hoping to split my keyboard input code into input.asm, and my Adlib sound card code into music.asm etc.

Anyway, my specific problem is that many of my procedures have lines like this that use EQU's in expressions.

```
  mov ax, ((scrWidth*YCoord)+XCoord)
```

When I move procedures that contain these lines into an external library and attempt to assemble that external library, MASM gives me the following error.

```
A2032: Illegal use of external
```

The error does make sense to me. Since they're external, the assembler doesn't directly know what scrWidth, YCoord, or XCoord are, so it can't add them together or multiply them. I guess that's why it can't actually generate the obj file.

So just to make things clear, here's two complete example files.

MAIN.ASM

```
TheStack SEGMENT STACK  

    DB 64 DUP ('THESTACK')

TheStack ENDS





VarData SEGMENT PUBLIC

PUBLIC const1,const2

    const1 EQU 1
    const2 EQU 2

VarData ENDS  





EXTRN Proc1:PROC  
Code SEGMENT PUBLIC

    assume cs:Code,ds:VarData

MAIN PROC

START:

    mov ax, VarData ;load DS
    mov ds, ax

    call Proc1      ;call external procedure

    mov ah,4ch      ;exit to dos
    mov al,0
    int 21h


Main ENDP

Code ENDS

     END Start
```

UTIL.ASM

```
VarData SEGMENT PUBLIC

EXTRN const1:ABS,const2:ABS

VarData ENDS   



Code SEGMENT PUBLIC

PUBLIC Proc1

    assume cs:Code,ds:VarData 


Proc1 PROC

    mov ax, (const1*const2)    ;this generates the error  
    ret

Proc1 ENDP


Code ENDS

     END
```

I did attempt a workaround by changing the EQU's in MAIN.ASM into variables instead of constants, then importing them into UTIL.ASM as actual bytes. Then from there I tried mapping them back into EQU's in Util.ASM, but the error is the same.

Anyone know of a workaround? I know this is a very obsolete assembler, but I really don't know if this was a known limitation that was fixed in later revisions of MASM.

Comment: Sounds like a perfect use for `include`.  Move all the common `equ` into their own file.

Comment: @David Well, that answers that. I completely forgot about `include` .

Comment: You also probably may find ways to reorganize your code a bit, so not every part of code will need to understand display coordinates/sizes, etc... but only display output related functions, etc. (it's still very likely that some constants will be needed in several "modules" at the same time, so include is needed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving this to an 'Answer' so it can be closed.

Just like high level languages, masm supports the ability to `include` files.

As Ped7g mentions, it's a "good programming technique" to scope your definitions.  For example your sound-related defines go at the top of your 'music.asm' file and your video-related defines at the top of your 'display.asm' file.

But some definitions apply more generally.  These might be `EQU`s, `EXTERN`s, `MACRO`s, `STRUCT`s, etc.  For these, you could have a general 'common.inc' that gets included by multiple files.

Comment: Solved, thanks. I found a pdf of the MASM 5.0 programmer's guide. There's a lot of useful information in there. I couldn't find one for 5.1, but it seems like everything in 5.0 still applies.